# Think we should now be kinder towards "Homework Questions"

Tags: discussion, homework

Given how many students are now studying from home, and out of formal school classes, I think we should now be kinder towards "Homework Questions." I'd propose:

- Making the home work policy known
- Offering a hint.
- Not voting to close a question until three days have passed to give the OP time to expand the post.

Comment: One could offer a hint and still close it. The OP can edit to expand if necessary. Or just direct them to chat.

Comment: No matter how kind you are, German children are Kinder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Making the home work policy known

This should really already be the case. Anecdotally I think that we are doing this quite well, but if there are cases where it *isn't* being done, please do do it.

> Offering a hint.

If you really want to, that's probably fine. It does already happen somewhat regularly. But please use comments, not answers.

As Jon mentioned, chat is an excellent alternative that allows for the back-and-forth which we generally don't like on main site. We are a bit more lenient with the long comment chains here, but that's not an excuse to do it all the time.

> Not voting to close a question until three days have passed to give the OP time to expand the post.

I don't really agree with this; OP can still edit the question when closed, and besides, the three-day wait is impractical to enforce.